# Make a nose cone in Fusion 360

Tags: 3d-design

I am new to Fusion 360 and I think I'm going straight to something complicated. Is there a way to make a nose cone for a model rocket? What tools would one you to accomplish this?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am actually not making a model rocket. I am making an electric hydrofoil. I just wanted the nose cone front piece. I see your point though for rockets!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft IME, model rocket nosecones like those from Estes are made from rigid plastics. They're hollow to be sure, but definitely not very soft or crushable.

Comment: @DLS3141  showing my age, I guess.  When I was a kid, the nose cones were balsa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a specific shape in mind and can create a sketch to represent that shape, you are halfway to your goal.

The concept is simple. Create a single line sketch that would represent the desired curve, starting from, in this example, the nose of the cone and traveling to the base. Create only one-half of the nose cone curve and maintain a "standard" axis reference, say, using the Y-axis as the rotation point.

The process is called [revolve. Fusion 360](http://help.autodesk.com/view/fusion360/ENU/?guid=GUID-5C62F370-7AB4-4DFD-BE61-F8830F30A6D7) supports this action directly.

```
In the Sculpt workspace, choose Create Revolve.
Select the profile to revolve.
In the Revolve dialog:
    Click Axis and then select the axis to revolve around.
    Choose Full or Angle to specify whether the revolution is full or to a specific angle.
    For Direction choose One Side, Two Side or Symmetrical.
    For Symmetry, choose None or Circular.
```

The above text is taken directly from the link. The specific web site also includes a Flash video of the steps involved.

If thickness is required for your creation, consider to draw the sketch from the nose to the base, then use Offset or hand sketch in a parallel line that returns to the nose. Ensure the base segment is joined and that the nose segments are open and are aligned to the Y-axis.

As the sketch is revolved, the nose sections will "close" while the base creates the closure necessary to make a solid that is hollow within and open at the bottom.

Use The Google or your preferred search engine with the terms "Fusion 360 Revolve" to find many tutorials and videos with the same information presented in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try model8ng the rocket into the workspace, and then you can extruder a nose cone from the top using a 30 degree angle

Comment: I don't really follow what you're saying. I'm good in Photoshop, but haven't yet mastered 3D modeling.

Comment: If you are extremely new, I would recommend watching a few online tutorials on the basics of modeling in fusion 360, and then work your way up fromm there.